# pyspark splitting with delimiter incorrectly (within higher order)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, apache-spark, pyspark

My task is to convert this spark python udf to pyspark native functions...

```
def parse_access_history_json_table(json_obj):
    '''
    extracts
    list of DBs, Schemas, Tables
    from json_obj field in access history
    '''
    db_list = set([])
    schema_list = set([])
    table_list = set([])
    try:
        for full_table_name in json_obj:
            full_table_name = full_table_name.lower()
            full_table_name_array = full_table_name.split(".")
            if len(full_table_name_array) == 3:
                db_list.add(full_table_name_array[0])
                schema_list.add(full_table_name_array[1])
                table_list.add(full_table_name_array[2])
            elif len(full_table_name_array) == 2:
                schema_list.add(full_table_name_array[0])
                table_list.add(full_table_name_array[1])
            else:
                table_list.add(full_table_name_array[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
    return (list(db_list), list(schema_list), list(table_list))
```

json_obj is array type col with example value [db1.s1.t1, s2.t2, t3]
eventually want 3 cols for db/schema/table each as an array of dbs etc... ['db1] ['s1','s2'] & tables ['t1','t2','t3']

I'm trying to convert this to a list of lists of x,y,z at first but splitting is going wrong.
(not sure if there's a faster/better way without using udf/lambda i.e python transformations)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("WordList", ArrayType(StringType()))])

test_list = [['database.schema.table']], [['t3','d1.s1.t1','s2.t2']]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)

df.withColumn("Filtered_Col", expr(f"transform(WordList,x -> split(x,'\.')  )")).show()
```

is giving

```
+-----------------+--------------------+
|         WordList|        Filtered_Col|
+-----------------+--------------------+
|[share_db.sc.tbl]|[[, , , , , , , ,...|
|[x a, d.s.t, d.s]|[[, , , ], [, , ,...|
+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Not sure why. I have spark 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the regex, the second parameter of the [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#split) function.

The backslash has to be escaped too, so `\\\.` will lead to the correct result:

```python
df.withColumn("Filtered_Col", expr("transform(WordList,x -> split(x,'\\\.')  )")).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
|WordList               |Filtered_Col                  |
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
|[database.schema.table]|[[database, schema, table]]   |
|[t3, d1.s1.t1, s2.t2]  |[[t3], [d1, s1, t1], [s2, t2]]|
+-----------------------+------------------------------+
```